# Reason for the choice of new 12th Apostle?

Tags: exegesis, acts, apostles, matthias

In [Acts 1:20–26](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Acts+1%3A20-26&version=NLT), the Apostles are choosing the 12th Apostle who will replace Judas:

> <sup>20</sup> Peter continued, “This was written in the book of Psalms, where it says, ‘Let his home become desolate, with no one living in it.’ It also says, ‘Let someone else take his position.’
>
> <sup>21</sup> “So now we must choose a replacement for Judas from among the men who were with us the entire time we were traveling with the Lord Jesus—<sup>22</sup> from the time he was baptized by John until the day he was taken from us. Whoever is chosen will join us as a witness of Jesus’ resurrection.”
>
> <sup>23</sup> So they nominated two men: Joseph called Barsabbas (also known as Justus) and Matthias. <sup>24</sup> Then they all prayed, “O Lord, you know every heart. Show us which of these men you have chosen <sup>25</sup> as an apostle to replace Judas in this ministry, for he has deserted us and gone where he belongs.” <sup>26</sup> Then they cast lots, and Matthias was selected to become an apostle with the other eleven. [NLT]

Does bible say anything about the choice of the new Apostle? What did Matthias have that Judas did not? Does the Bible explain this?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I know the answer will be extremely unsatisfying, but the answer is right there in the question.  Verses 24-26.  They didn't know which to pick, so they prayed and asked God to show them by directing the outcome of casting lots, then they trusted Him to do so.  There's really nothing more said, and really no reason to say more.

In essence, they threw up their hands and said "We don't know who to choose, God.  We're just going to cast lots and trust you to pick the right man."

Casting lots, if you're not familiar with the term, is similar to drawing straws, or flipping a coin.  It's mentioned elsewhere in Scripture as well.  There's an article here about it:  http://www.biblestudy.org/question/what-is-casting-lots.html

Comment: ...So they just choose by flipping coins???
...Well then, schools should not blame kids for doing that.

Comment: Don't forget that God was already working miraculously and visibly in their lives.  I would imagine that believing He could direct the outcome of a "coin toss" would be relatively easy after raising Christ from the dead.  Not to mention that they accepted God as having created the universe, flooding the earth, parting the Red Sea...

Comment: It is also noticeable that the church never used lots to fill a position again.

Comment: And, nothing further is recorded about either. Many commentators believe that God had intended for that 12th slot to be filled by Paul, but Peter jumped the gun.

Answer (score 1):

Acts 1:8    Jesus orders the disciples to go to Jerusalem and await the coming of the Holy Spirit. 
Acts 1:13   One hundred twenty disciples gather in an upper room at Jerusalem.
Acts 1:21   Peter determines basic qualifications for candidates for the 12th apostle.
        No precedence for his qualification.  Certainly not Jesus' method.
        Many of the one hundred twenty initially disqualified.
Acts 1:23   The disciples select two candidates.
Acts 1:24   Now, for the first time, they consult God in prayer as to which of the two men THEY have chosen Jesus wants for His twelfth disciple.
Acts 1:26   The disciples set forth, or cast or give their lots. (Gamble or vote?)
        The lot falls on Matthias.  Did God play any part in this decision?

Comment: Welcome to Christianity.SE! I hope you'll spend some time browsing the questions and answers here. About your answer, it's a little unclear as to whether you're actually *answering* the question, or asking a new question of your own. For some tips on writing good answers here, please see: [What makes a good supported answer?](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/692/what-makes-a-good-supported-answer) For a quick introduction to this site, please take the [Site Tour](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/tour).

Comment: More specifically about your answer: Where do you get the number "one hundred twenty" initial candidates? Also, casting lots was seen as a method of letting God make the choice.

Comment: Acts 1:15  And in those days Peter stood up in the midst of the disciples, and said, (the number of names together were about an hundred and twenty,)

Comment: Ah, yes. I wasn't looking early enough in the story. Thanks. Presumably only a few of them had been with Jesus from the beginning of his ministry. Most would have been later converts.

Answer (score 1):

### Reason for the choice of a new 12th Apostle

I agree with David Stratton, except I believe Peter gives the answer to your question in verses 20-22

> Peter continued, “**This was written in the book of Psalms**, where it says, ‘Let his home become desolate, with no one living in it (Psalm 69:25).’ It also says, ‘Let someone else take his position (Psalm 109:8).’
>
> “So now we must choose a replacement for Judas from among the men who **were with us the entire time we were traveling with the Lord Jesus**—
>
> from the time he was baptized by John until the day he was taken from us. Whoever is chosen will join us as a **witness** of Jesus’ resurrection.”

According to Peter, Psalms predicted what the Bible had to say about this. Peter had that authority because he was a real Apostle, chosen by Yeshua. This was after the Apostles had received the holy spirit, which happened in John 20:22 before Acts begins:

> And when he had said this, he breathed on them, and saith unto them, **Receive ye the Holy Ghost**

Yeshua told them that after they received the holy spirit, it would tell them what they should :

> "Howbeit when it, the spirit of truth, is come, **it will guide you into all truth**: for it shall not speak of itself; but whatsoever it shall hear, that shall it speak: and it will shew you things to come." John 16:13

The holy spirit told Peter that he needed to choose another Apostle, and Peter rightfully decided that this person was required to be with them from the beginning, and to be a witness of the resurrection. This is also why Yeshua chose his Twelve:

> "But when the comforter is come, whom I will send unto you from the Father, the spirit of truth which proceedeth from the Father, it shall testify of me:
>
> **And ye also shall bear witness, because ye have been with me from the beginning.**" John 15:26-27

Note: All verse are from the KJV, though some capitalizations and pronouns have been edited.